# Playscape SDK 1.17 Error!!! Could not retrieve configuration from the server

Tags: playscape

While building the game with the latest Playscape SDK (1.17), there is an error that says: "Error!!! Could not retrieve configuration from the server."

Comment: I would vote to close - not enough information posted by OP

Comment: Check, please, if you set right API KEY

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly for me, I realized that the playscape api key field was containing the incorrect key.